# MathJax superscript

Tags: mathjax

How can I make this image:

[image: expected result]

Result with MathJax

[image: Result with MathJax]

```
{}_{88}^{226}\mathrm{Ra},\;{}_6^{12}\mathrm C,\;{}_{14}^{30}\mathrm{Si},\;{}_{92}^{235}\mathrm U
```

Comment: Why did you expect that?

Comment: edit with mspaint picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscripts and superscripts are aligned to the left.

If centering them is enough for you, then you can use `smallmatrix`:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
$$
\begin{smallmatrix}
  112 \\
  4
\end{smallmatrix}
\mathrm{Ra}
$$
```

But if you want them aligned to the right, I think your only option is using `array`, but then the numbers appear too separated.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
$$
{
  \scriptsize
  \begin{array}{r}
    112 \\
    4
  \end{array}
}
\mathrm{Ra}
$$
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more example (based on **[MathJax/mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/)**):

```js
window.MathJax = {
  config: ["MMLorHTML.js"],
  jax: ["input/TeX", "input/MathML", "input/AsciiMath", "output/HTML-CSS", "output/NativeMML"],
  extensions: ["tex2jax.js", "mml2jax.js", "asciimath2jax.js", "MathMenu.js", "MathZoom.js"],
  asciimath2jax: {
    delimiters: [
      ['`', '`'],
      ['$', '$']
    ]
  },
  TeX: {
    extensions: ["AMSmath.js", "AMSsymbols.js", "noErrors.js", "noUndefined.js", "mhchem.js"]
  },
  tex2jax: {
    inlineMath: [
      ['$', '$'],
      ["\\(", "\\)"]
    ],
    processEscapes: true
  }
};
```

```css
.MathJax_CHTML {
  font-size: 30px !important;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>


<p>
  $\ce{^{226}_{88}$Ra$}$, $\ce{^{12}_{6}$C$}$, $\ce{^{30}_{14}$Si$}$, $\ce{^{235}_{92}$U$}$
</p>
```

Comment: Given the context of the original question, using `mhchem` is obviously the correct answer!